# What are those little colored cubes in Interface Builder Identity Inspector

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

There are 7 colored cubes under IB's Identity Inspector. What are they used for?
I tried to click on them, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer...>>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379569/label-color-under-the-identity-inspector-in-xcode-4/10380418#10380418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're supposed to provide a color label so you can easily identify the object in Interface Builder. If you select a file or folder from the Finder and choose File > Get Info, you can set a color label and see what setting a color label is supposed to do. Like you, I have also found that clicking a color does nothing in Interface Builder.

Comment: @Mark Szymczyk : See my and may be you want to know something about this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379569/label-color-under-the-identity-inspector-in-xcode-4/10380418#10380418